# expression engine using groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to expose a expression engine built on top of groovy for end users. I have some excel style keywords and user can use variables within those keywords (which need to be substituted at runtime) for evaluation.
example, static keyword FIRSTCHAR(varName) will return the first character of a string. I have got this to work in a way.

Current Implementation
I have overridden the groovy class loader to create a compilation unit with an overridden PrimaryClassNodeOperation something like

```
class MyGroovyClassLoader extends GroovyClassLoader {
    protected CompilationUnit createCompilationUnit(
            CompilerConfiguration config, CodeSource source) {
        CompilationUnit cu = super.createCompilationUnit(config, source);
        cu.addPhaseOperation(new PrimaryClassNodeOperation(){

            @Override
            public void call(SourceUnit source, GeneratorContext context, ClassNode classNode)
                    throws CompilationFailedException {
               source.getAST().getStatementBlock().visit(visitor);
            }
        }, Phases.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS);
        return cu;
    }
}
```

The visitor then recognizes the static expression and variable expression. However, using this approach I am having difficulties in

1) Supporting variable names with dot (.) since dot is considered a property expression. Can I during this phase keep the property expression as variable expression.

2) Also, for an expression like (left(name,1)=='S' && right(name,1)=='n') [first character in name is s and last is n] - I want the equal to check to be single equals rather than double equals, and/AND instead of && or .and() so something like (left(name,1)='S' and right(name,1)='n')

What's the best way to achieve such customizations?

Comment: Have you considered writing your own parser using something like [parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled) or [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/)?  I have a feeling there's only so much you can do with Groovy DSLs and when you start trying to define your own operators you're probably heading straight for an edge...

Comment: antlr's AntlrParserPlugin is used for building the AST. I was wondering if I could do something in the visitor, replace the property node with variable expression when the property node gets visited or maybe within the argument list expression visit? I know this will make it specific to the given use case but I am okay with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to use a custom parser (since you dont want your users to write any groovy) and then use groovy to actually implement the back-end

eg: Very indicative, your implementation can vary

```
(left(name,1)='S')
```

For the snipet above, tokens could be method:left, args:((var:name),(val:1)), exp:EQUALS, val:'S'
Have a map at the back which equates your tokens to  groovy equivalents

You could then be fire your parsed tokens against a groovy class, of course the methods and arguments dont exist, use some groovy tricks to translate it to your actual implementation [1](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy)

Comment: can you add some meat to your answer.. are you advising converting (left(name,1)='S') to (left(name,1)=='S') using a parser? I can do that, all I am after is to find if there's an easy/reusable way of converting an expression to AST and then back into an expression?

Comment: Yes,the problem with hooking into the AST is that customization gets very hacky and non extendable, Preprocess your client DSL using a custom parser and convert special expressions like '=' into '==' and any other special symbols into groovy equivalents and then execute it. This way you can handle any future upgrades at the parse level